# Oracle SQL 00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis"

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to insert values into a table from another table. Replacing any possible nulls with 'Undefined', and also I created a sequence to populate one of my columns. I keep getting an error on the second line.

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_DIM
SELECT PRODUCT_SEQ.NEXTVAL AS PRODUCT_KEY, 
       NVL((PRODUCTID, PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, PRODUCTLINEID),'Undefined')
FROM PRODUCT_T;
```

Answer (score 1):

NVL only takes 2 parameters (maximum).  Look at using COALESCE instead, ie.

```
COALESCE(param1, param2, param3, .... )
```

Comment: I do wonder what genius back in the day decided that two arguments would be enough for the `nvl()` function, and why nobody ever added any more in all the releases since then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `COALESCE` function as Connor demonstrates.

With `NVL` you need to nest the function like shown below:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_DIM
SELECT PRODUCT_SEQ.NEXTVAL AS PRODUCT_KEY, 
    NVL(PRODUCTID, NVL(PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, NVL(PRODUCTLINEID, 'Undefined')))
FROM PRODUCT_T;
```

Comment: PRODUCT_SEQ, @Kiran, is a *sequence*.

Comment: aha, I see , let me edit my answer. Thanks @Littlefoot and removed the comment on product_seq

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you're, actually, inserting 4 different columns so you need 4 separate NVLs, but it is difficult to guess (so that's what we're exactly doing - guessing).

If you specified the column list that should be populated in the PRODUCT_DIM table, it would be easier to answer.

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_DIM
  (product_key, 
   productid, 
   productdescription, 
   productlineid
  )
  SELECT PRODUCT_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 
         NVL(PRODUCTID         , 'Undefined'),
         NVL(PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, 'Undefined'),
         NVL(PRODUCTLINEID     , 'Undefined')
  FROM PRODUCT_T;
```